# not all arguments converted during string formatting when mentioning users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot that will log the edited or deleted messages.

At some point the program is considring the author id as string for some reason.

the code of `on_message_edit`doesn't work like the `on_message` code

when I am on the `on_message` I mention the author like this at it works

```
UserID = message.author.id
await bot.send_message(whatever channel, 'This is <@%s>' % (UserId))
```

but when I tried to do the same mentioning method on the `on_message_edit` it didn't work. I did

```
 @bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    MemberId = after.author.id
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'), 'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``' + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ' % (MemberId))
```

and I get this error

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message_edit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ezter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\programing\Discord Bots\Test bot\Setup.py", line 25, in on_message_edit
    await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'), 'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``' + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ' % (MemberId))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `%s`

```
>>> '12%s' + '45' % '3'
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

>>> '12%s' % '3' + '45'
'12345'
```

In your case you want

```
await bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'), 'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``' % MemberId + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ')
```

If you're on Python3.6+, f-strings are even cleaner

```
channel = bot.get_channel('480495197034381332')
message = f'The user <@{MemberId}> has edited his message from ``{before.content}`` to `` {after.content}``'
await bot.send_message(channel, message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Operator `%` has higher precedence than `+`. See [the docs on operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

So a code which does `a + b % c` evaluates `b % c` first.

In your code, that would mean, the first thing evaluated is ``` ' `` ' % (MemberId) ``` and that fails because there is no `%s` in ``` ' `` ' ```:

```
'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``' + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ' % (MemberId)
```

This could be fixed by adding parenthesis around everything before `%`, e.g.:

```
bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'),
                 ('The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``'
                  + before.content + '`` to `` ' + after.content + ' `` ')
                 % (MemberId))
```

**But that is still a rather poor way to do it.**

For example, it fails if there is a `%` in `before.content` or in `after.content`. It also fails if `MemberId` is a tuple.

**This would be correct:**

```
bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'),
                 'The user <@%s> have edited his message from ``%s``'
                 ' to ``%s`` ' % (MemberId, before.content, after.content))
```

**This would be even better:**

```
bot.send_message(bot.get_channel('480495197034381332'),
                 f'The user <@{MemberId}> have edited his message from '
                 f'``{before.content}`` to ``{after.content}`` ')
```